# Jquery Validate on dynamic form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I use Jquery validation (http://jqueryvalidation.org) to validate form.
My code:

```
<div id="form-section"></div>
<button id="add-form" type="button">Add form</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add-form').click(function () {
            $('#form-section').html('<form id="myform"> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required> <button type="submit">Submit</button> </form>');
        });

        $('#myform').validate();
    })
</script>
```

But `$('#myform').validate();` not working. How can I validate a dynamic form like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `#myform` element doesn't exist in the DOM when you first call `validate()`. Instead, place that line within the `click()` handler, after the `form` is created:

```
$('#add-form').click(function () {
    $('#form-section').html('<form id="myform"> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required> <button type="submit">Submit</button> </form>');
    $('#myform').validate();
});
```

Comment: Yes, this work fine, but is there any way to use it with jQuery .on() function, such as $('#form-section').on() ?.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `on()` relates to an event handler, which you already have in the form of `click()`.

Comment: I dont know if Jquery Validate supports an event like 'submit' event. Example: $('#form-section').on('validate', '#myform', function(){ // some code });

Comment: If you want to run some code when the `validate()` method is called use the events it provides in the optional parameters. Check their documentation for more information.